# Help! My bash script stopped working as intended!

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, output, history

I am trying to get a very basic bash script to work but the output for the history command stopped working properly!!

[image]

This is the output

```
#!/bin/bash -i
history
```

And that's the code

Any insight as to why this is happening would be greatly appreciated. I am running Ubuntu on a virtual machine with Oracle VM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, `history` command is disabled in bash script see tldp: [History Commands](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/histcommands.html)

Use:

```
#!/bin/bash -i
HISTFILE=~/.bash_history
set -o history
history
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! Had to restart the machine to have the proper output printed out but it all worked out in the end <3